# angular-phonecat application using Node.js error 404 Not Found: /app/index.html

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I am running http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_00 
on my windows machine

It was working fine till yesterday.
Today it is giving following error

404 Not Found: /app/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I run node script/web-server.js or cd into script and run node web-server.js instead of just ./web-server.js, node exits with an error that it cannot find the file web-server.js